# Exceptions from Service to webcontroller layer in Spring application

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, architecture

I am building a web application (which has both webcontrollers which move to another page, as well as restcontrollers, which give a REST-ful result), and something isn't very clear to me, based on the documentation.

What is the recommended strategy regarding throwing exceptions from the service layer (or just your business logic implemented in @Service's or @Component's) when they're being called from an @Controller? Do the @Controllers have a try- catch logic for all possible exceptions that the Service might throw? What about unchecked exceptions?

Answer (score 0):

There would be multiple options. This [blog post](https://spring.io/blog/2013/11/01/exception-handling-in-spring-mvc) at spring.io seems to have explained it very well.